# Can we have communications in a web-based dapp?

Tags: web3js, smart-contract-wallets, chainlink

I want to create a ui with web3js for some etherium smart contracts. However, I like to enquire the wallet owners whether or not they will accept the transaction
Is it possible to send them some sort of communication? If yes, how? And if no, is it possible to use chainlink for sending normal emails for enquiry?

In other words, how can we send an email(or any type of communication) to owner of a wallet in a dapp?

Answer (score 0):

[Arbo94](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/users/93625/arbo94),

The concept of oracles is for querying data from the off-chain world and executing smart contract functions from this data.
It's not to trigger external services like sending email, for example.
I think Chainlink will not help in your case.